# How to get OpenAI/baselines to work on MacOS Monterey, M1 Pro?

Tags: python, macos, openai-api

I've been struggling for days trying to get any repo implementing PPO running on my Macbook, so I was wondering what's the trick? I'm currently trying to get the OpenAI/Baselines repo to work, carefully following their README, and after having solved various undocumented issues ( different tensorflow pkg sources, missing tensorflow-macos fork in setup script, deprecated numpy functionalities, hardcoded gcc pkg version that is incompatible with MacOS, etc etc ) I'm now stuck at this error:

> **gym.error.DependencyNotInstalled:
> dlopen(<...>/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mujoco_py/generated/cymj_2.1.2.14_310_macextensionbuilder_310.so,
> 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_mj_Euler'**.
> (HINT: you
> need to install mujoco_py, and also perform the setup instructions
> here: https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/.)

I already installed mujoco_py, and I have no idea what is wrong here as I don't understand the error and couldn't really find anything about this that works.

If anyone has any insights into this or knows an "easy" way to get the OpenAI/baselines repo working on MacOS Monterey (with M1 Pro Chip), or even any repo implementing PPO in Python for that matter, I'd very much appreciate it!

P.S. For reference, this is my pip freeze:

```
absl-py==1.4.0
astunparse==1.6.3
atari-py==0.2.9
attrs==22.2.0
cachetools==5.3.0
certifi==2022.12.7
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==3.0.1
click==8.1.3
cloudpickle==1.2.2
Cython==0.29.33
dill==0.3.6
exceptiongroup==1.1.0
fasteners==0.18
flatbuffers==23.1.21
future==0.18.3
gast==0.4.0
glfw==2.5.6
google-auth==2.16.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.51.1
gym==0.13.1
h5py==3.8.0
idna==3.4
imageio==2.25.0
iniconfig==2.0.0
joblib==1.2.0
keras==2.11.0
libclang==15.0.6.1
Markdown==3.4.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
mujoco==2.3.1.post1
mujoco-py==2.1.2.14
numpy==1.23.5
oauthlib==3.2.2
opencv-python==4.7.0.68
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==23.0
Pillow==9.4.0
pluggy==1.0.0
progressbar2==4.2.0
protobuf==3.19.4
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.21
pyglet==1.3.2
PyOpenGL==3.1.6
pytest==7.2.1
python-utils==3.4.5
requests==2.28.2
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rsa==4.9
scipy==1.10.0
six==1.16.0
tensorboard==2.11.2
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
tensorflow-estimator==2.11.0
tensorflow-macos==2.11.0
tensorflow-metal==0.7.0
termcolor==2.2.0
tomli==2.0.1
tqdm==4.64.1
typing_extensions==4.4.0
urllib3==1.26.14
Werkzeug==2.2.2
wrapt==1.14.1
```